# How to make a table with square cells responsive?

Tags: css

I'm making an implementation of Conway's Game of Life.

For the GUI I'm creating a web, and I'd like to show a table with responsive square cells, no matter the number of cells. Any help?

Here I show what I've done:
HTML

```js
function createBoard(heigh, width){
    console.log("Executing function");
    var table,row,options,cell;

    table=document.getElementById("board");

    for (var i=0; i<heigh;i++){
        
        row=document.createElement("tr");
        
        for (var j=0;j<width;j++){
            cell=document.createElement("td")
           
            cell.id= "cell-"+i+"-"+j;
            cell.classList.add("cell","death")
            //cell.addEventListener("click",changeCellClass(cell.id,"death"))
            cell.onclick=function(){changeCellClass(this,"death")};
            //cell.onmousedown=function(){changeCellClass(this,"death")};
            cell.onmouseover=function(){this.style.backgroundColor="yellowgreen"};
            cell.onmouseleave=function(){this.style.backgroundColor="darkcyan"};
            //cell.addEventListener("click",console.log(cell.id))
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        table.appendChild(row)
    }
}

function changeCellClass(cell,currentClass){
    console.log(cell.id)
    console.log(currentClass)
    cell.classList.remove(currentClass)
    if(currentClass=="death"){
        cell.classList.add("live")
        currentClass="live"
        cell.style.backgroundColor="yellowgreen";
        cell.onmouseover=function(){this.style.backgroundColor="darkcyan"};
        cell.onmouseleave=function(){this.style.backgroundColor="yellowgreen"};
        console.log(cell.id+" 've changed to live")
    }else{
        cell.classList.add("death")
        currentClass="death"
        cell.style.backgroundColor="darkcyan";
        cell.onmouseover=function(){this.style.backgroundColor="yellowgreen"};
        cell.onmouseleave=function(){this.style.backgroundColor="darkcyan"};
        console.log(cell.id+" 've changed to death")
        
    }
    cell.onclick=function(){changeCellClass(this,currentClass)};
}

createBoard(50,50);
```

```css
table{
    height: 70%;
    width: 70%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 1px black;
    border-collapse:collapse
    }

td {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

.death{
    background-color:darkcyan;
}

.live{
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}


p{
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Conway's Game of Life</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.8.10/brython.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.8.10/brython_stdlib.min.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js" defer></script>
        <!-- -->
        <!--<script src="http://localhost:8000/Game/Web/index.py" type="text/python" defer></script>-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body onload="brython(1)">
        <h1 id=test>Conway's Game of Life</h1>
        <p>The Game of Life, also known simply as Life, is a cellular automaton devised by the British mathematician John Horton Conway in 1970.
            It is a zero-player game, meaning that its evolution is determined by its initial state, requiring no further input.
            One interacts with the Game of Life by creating an initial configuration and observing how it evolves.
            It is Turing complete and can simulate a universal constructor or any other Turing machine.
        </p>

        <table id="board">
        </table>
        
        <h2>Rules</h2>
        <p>
            <ul>
                <li>Any live cell with two or three live neighbours survives.</li>
                <li>Any dead cell with three live neighbours becomes a live cell.</li>
                <li>All other live cells die in the next generation. Similarly, all other dead cells stay dead.</li>
            </ul>
        </p>

        <h2>Patterns</h2>
        <h3>Still life</h3>
        <h3>Oscillators</h3>
        <h3>Spaceships</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've look for a lot of sites and haven't found nothing suitable for this problem (the solution I've found are for a particular height or width in cells, not something that adapats)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after doing some look into, I've a solution suitable for my problem: using jquery.

```
function windowReszie(){
   var size =$("td").width();
   $("td").height(size);
}
```

Then add this fuction on window's resize event and it is done

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){windowReszie()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using GRID  e.g.

```
.gameboard{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows:repeat(50, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(50,1fr)
    grid-gap:3px;
    height:70%;
}
.death{
    background-color:darkcyan;
}

.live{
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class = "gameboard">
 <div class="live"><div>
....
<div class="death"><div>
<div class="live"><div>
...
<div class="live"><div>
</div>
```